# How to programmatically extract audio mp3 from a youtube video?

Tags: c#, asp.net, audio, mp3, youtube

Does anyone have any sample asp.net C# code to extract the audio from a youtube video link and save it as a mp3 file. Someone recommended using wget and ffmpeg which I installed and am trying to shell a command, but get an exception below. Sample code is listed below.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files\\GnuWin32\\bin\\wget.exe http://www.youtube.com/get_video?video_id=... | ffmpeg -i - audio.mp3";
proc.Start();
```

Comment: please specify the exception.

Comment: {"The system cannot find the file specified"}

Comment: I'm still unable to get a batch file to run properly. Can someone help troubleshoot? I bring up cmd.exe and go to directory where ffmpeg is in and try running this command:
"C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\\bin\wget.exe http://www.youtube.com/get_video?video_id=2O0kuoiAm2A | ffmpeg.exe -i - c:/temp/mp3/audio.mp3"

I get a system cannot find the file specified error.

Comment: I recently read downloading a video from youtube is no longer possible. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: You are downloading the Youtube HTML page not the video file !!

Answer (score 3):

You should use the [`WebClient` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) to download the file, and use [ffmpeg-sharp](http://code.google.com/p/ffmpeg-sharp/) to transcode it.

Answer (score 3):

You are seeing "file not found" because you are not specifying a valid file name i.e.:

```
"C:\\Program Files\\GnuWin32\\bin\\wget.exe http://www.youtube.com/get_video?video_id=... | ffmpeg -i - audio.mp3"
```

The above is not a file name, it is a file name plus some arguments, that is then piped to another executable.

As you are trying to run two executables here (wget and ffmpeg) an approach here would be to write a script (e.g a batch file) that wraps up these two executable calls and then execute the script and pass the url argument to it.

Comment: I'm still unable to get a batch file to run properly. Can someone help troubleshoot? I bring up cmd.exe and go to directory where ffmpeg is in and try running this command: "C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\\bin\wget.exe youtube.com/get_video?video_id=2O0kuoiAm2A | ffmpeg.exe -i - c:/temp/mp3/audio.mp3" I get a system cannot find the file specified error

Comment: I recently read downloading a video from youtube is no longer possible. Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 0):

The Process.Start(string) method is meant to start a process with no arguments. Therfore as chibacity said, you get an exception because the whole string "C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin\wget.exe http://www.youtube.com/get_video?video_id=... | ffmpeg -i - audio.mp3" is treated as the file name to execute. To start a process with arguments use the Process.Start(string,string) method : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa326952%28v=VS.71%29.aspx.

Comment: I recently read downloading a video from youtube is no longer possible. Can anyone confirm?